# make a item list with a mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to upgrade my item list to an item list that gets the data from a MySQL server. But how do I do, I have tried to make a for loop, but it won't let me do it.

```
items = new List<Item>();
        var _items = new List<Item>
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < Text.length; i++)
        {
            new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = text[i], Description = description[i] },
        }


        };


        foreach (Item item in _items)
            {
                items.Add(item);
            }

        isInitialized = true;
```

Comment: You aren't using any of the traditional classes for connecting to a database server.. do you need to know how to do that exactly?

Comment: For the moments, this code doesn't do anything related to database.

Comment: i know how to connect to my server, but need help to loop items because i cant loop it. Im a new programmer :D

Comment: @Mikkelkø what issue are you encountering exactly?

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-mysqlcommand.html

Comment: my problem now is how i can loop though the data i got in my array, and make items in the loop

Comment: @Mikkelkø Well the code you've provided should work just fine.. are you getting any specific errors or exceptions or does the data just not copy over correctly?

Comment: @RH6 i am just getting red lines under det code i posted above

Comment: @Mikkelkø What are they saying? You didn't declare your items variable for one, that should fix a few of the errors, see my answer for how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For one you aren't declaring your items variable, it should be

```
 List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

Other than that the code looks fine.

Comment: didn't help i sorry i am still getting red lines :D

Comment: @Mikkelkø Tell me what they say.

Comment: var _items = new List<Item>
            { //her it says expected "}"
for (int i = 0; i < Text.length; i++)
            {
                new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = text[i], Description = description[i] };
            
            }

Comment: @Mikkelkø You have forgotten to close one of your code blocks, its most likely not related to the code you've provided. Look at all of your blocks to see if they've been closed, make sure your namespace and class definition blocks are closed as well.

Comment: if i remove the var _items = new List<Item> 
            { then the red lines are away. But i dosent make the items right :D